# How to remove a header from a file that is bmp but with no import of any libraries in python

Tags: python, image, header, bmp

How to remove a header from a file that is .bmp but with no import of any libraries in python and reading byte byte f.read(1)?

Comment: Do you know how large the header is?

Comment: No, but I think is 14... not sure...

Answer (score 2):

You have to look up the [BMP file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) and use it to figure out how to parse the header.

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Bitmap_file_header), the header starts as follows:

```
Offset# Size    Purpose
0000h   2 bytes the header field used to identify the BMP & DIB file is 0x42 0x4D in hexadecimal, same as BM in ASCII. [...]
0002h   4 bytes the size of the BMP file in bytes
0006h   2 bytes reserved; actual value depends on the application that creates the image
0008h   2 bytes reserved; actual value depends on the application that creates the image
000Ah   4 bytes the offset, i.e. starting address, of the byte where the bitmap image data (pixel array) can be found.
```

So what you want to do is read the bytes at offsets 10-13, parse them as a 4-byte integer, and that integer represents where in the file to seek to get all of the image data. Then you just have to read all the image data and put it in another file. I am not sure why you would want to do this, though, since without the header it will be extremely difficult to tell what format the image data is in.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you want to say :) I did split them and i parse them as a 4-bit integer but my problem is the header. I can not removed it...

Comment: @user3238361: you have to write out a new file which includes everything but the header.

Comment: and how is that possible not to include the header, that is my question, i do not know how to do it... :)

Comment: @user3238361: say the data starts at byte 1000 and `f` is your file object. Do `f.seek(1000); img_data = f.read();` now `img_data` is all the data without the header. save this to another file. alternatively, say `file_data` contains the entire file including header. then just save `file_data[1000:]` to another file.

Answer (score 1):

Use a hex editor, remove the header file bytes and save the altered file - minus the header. There are also a few bytes at the end of a Bitmap file to remove if you are being thorough. Try XVI32 hex editor or HxD. Both are very good hex editors and they are FREE. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

BMP isn't a text file format, it's a binary format. That means you have to read it in binary mode. And you can't read it "line by line", because it doesn't have lines of text to read. Since a bytes object isn't mutable, you will probably want to copy it into a bytearray to work with. So:

```
 with open('spam.bmp', 'rb') as f:
    data = bytearray(f.read())
```